# Force redirect http to https when iframing

Tags: nginx, vps

Hy, I know there's a lot of threads asking this but I didn't find anything that works for me, I use Lets Encrypt for SSL, but when I try to Iframe a page with my domain it loads a blank page since the link has a redirect chain which involves some http urls. So I need some advice or refference how to configure my VPS to force redirects to https when Iframing...

Comment: That's not clear. Is your site inside the iframe? Or did you put some other site in an iframe on your site?

Comment: My site is secure, and I am trying to load another site in an Iframe on my site, but I am not sure is there any way to force https with the site which is in Iframe...

Comment: You would have to fix the other website.